# HashMap holding older value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a scenario where I iterate over a set of rows from a resultset obtained from query

-->QUERY

```
System.out.println("---Iterating Events---");
while (rs.next()) {

startOfMethod(rs);
}

startOfMethod(ResultSet result)
{
HashMap hmap;
String applicationGroupMap;
String description; 
description = result.getString("description"); //description is an XML string
hmap = new XMLRead().xmlDataOutput(description); //This is a separate class which returns a hashmap
applicationGroupMap = (String) hmap.get("Attribute.applicationGroupMap");
}
```

The problem is that sometimes when it iterates to the second row from first one and the second row does not have a "Attribute.applicationGroupMap, it retains the older value.

Can anyone tell me how do I refresh the hmap on every iteration?

Code which returns Hmap :-

```
try {
                Document doc = convertToDocument(xmlStr);

                String hashKey = "";
                String hashValue = "";

                NodeList listOfKeyValues = doc.getElementsByTagName("k");

                for (int s = 0; s < listOfKeyValues.getLength(); s++) {

                        Node firstNode = listOfKeyValues.item(s);

                        if (firstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                Element firstElement = (Element) firstNode;

                                NodeList keyList = firstElement.getChildNodes();
                                hashKey = ((Node) keyList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();

                                NodeList listOfvalues = doc.getElementsByTagName("v");

                                Node secondNode = listOfvalues.item(s);

                                Element valueElement = (Element) secondNode;

                                NodeList valueList = valueElement.getChildNodes();
                                if (valueList.getLength() != 0) {
                                        hashValue = ((Node) valueList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                } else {
                                        hashValue = "";
                                }
                                hsMap.put(hashKey, hashValue);
                        }
                }
        } catch (Throwable t) {

                t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hsMap;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's a bug in the code returning the HashMap. You should show us that code. Any reason you aren't using generics, by the way?

Comment: Jon, it was written way back, and no time to change all, just a defect am trying to fix. I agree using generics will be better.

Comment: This seems incomplete.  your startOfMethod method isn't valid, and doesn't return anything or use anything.  It's likely in whatever code is actually using the data - but hard to say without seeing it.

Comment: Added the method which returns hmap

Comment: How is `hsMap` initialized inside that `XMLRead` class?

Comment: public static HashMap hsMap = new HashMap();

Comment: i think it shouldn't be static?

Comment: Exactly. That's what's keeping it around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments, you have two options:

Change the declaration of `hsMap` in `XMLRead` to

```
public HashMap hsMap = new HashMap();
```

(Not `static`. It might also be more correct to make it `private`, but that's not related to your problem.)

--OR--

In `startOfMethod` do

```
hmap.clear();
```

to clear the map after you've gotten what you wanted from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hmap` variable shouldn't even be a member variable, let alone static. It should be method-local, and the method should allocate a new one every call.

A more accurate version of your title would be 'Old `HashMap` holding old value'.